# Uploading files behind Amazon Load Balancer

Tags: upload, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I want to know if their might be a problem uploading images to my website when I have several EC2 servers behind a load balancer without stickiness. I thought about using [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com), but I am not sure if it will work every time when user upload files to the server. Any insight on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on where you end up saving the files. Typically for a farm, you are better off saving the files on S3 (since you are already on EC2). That way, all servers have access to it. Saving it on a particular server handing that particular session doesn't scale at all. Ideally, you would want your servers to be completely stateless so you can scale them up or down. Saving the file on a particular server make it stateful.

What library you use on the client to upload is irrelevant for this discussion. Uploadify seems to do the job very well.